# Telerik Dropdown

Tags: telerik

I have binded a Telerik dropdownlist with viewbag. It's working well. But listed items are wrapped.
  Instead of coming in single line like 'United Arab Emirates' , It comes like
United
Arab
Emirates

How could I unwrap the line item

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Is this in regard to Telerik ASP.net controls?

If so,

Have you tried setting the "NoWrap" property in the aspx of the combo box?

```
NoWrap="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check the width of the control, which would include the container for dropdown list values.  You may have to change the CSS width... but it wouldn't be dynamic based on the dropdown values.

Here is a [Telerik suggestion](http://www.telerik.com/forums/dropdown-list-without-ellipsis-or-wrapping).

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually using a dropdown list, or are you using a Telerik ComboBox?  The combobox has a lot more options than a normal drop list, and in most cases it is very easy to convert from one control to the other.  It's like a drop down list on steriods.  Using the combo box, there is an awesome property called DropDownAutoWidth which you can set to enabled/disabled.  Enabling will auto-size the width of the drop down based on the items that are in the drop down.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code at this demo: [Prevent Wrap of Kendo UI Drop down list item](http://jsfiddle.net/sun21170/TBkEe/487/).

In the demo, you can change the text of any item in drop down and you will notice that the drop down width will automatically adjust so no wrapping of any item occurs. Put the JavaScript in this demo inside the `document.ready` event.

**Markup**

```
<select id="ddl1">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">option 2</option>
    <option value="3">longer option 3</option>
    <option value="4">even longer option 4 dssd s dssas </option>
</select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ddl1").kendoDropDownList();
    setWidth($("#ddl1"));
});

function setWidth(el)
{
    var d = el;
    var p = d.data("kendoDropDownList").popup.element;
    var w = p.css("visibility","hidden").show().outerWidth();
    p.hide().css("visibility","visible");
    d.closest(".k-widget").width(w);
}
```